# RxJs 'from' is returning Observable of type unknown

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```ts
import { Tenant } from './tenant';

import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export const testTenants: Tenant[] = [
    {
        'tenant_id': 'ID1'
    }
]

const tenants$: Observable<Tenant>= from(testTenants);
```

I am getting the error:

```
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Tenant>'
```

Typescript thinks the `from` function is returning `Observable<unknown>`. How do I get it to recognise it as a `Observable<Tenant>`?

Comment: You already have the value, that should be `of`; `from` can only imply the generic type T from an ObservableInput: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `of` instead of `from`

```
const tenants$: Observable<Tenant[]>= of(testTenants);
```